# Wrong static files loaded

Tags: magento2, theme

I've just deployed a new env and I'm getting some strange thing.

In the frontend, my static files load properly from my custom theme

```
frontend/Website/default/fr_FR
```

But once I come into the admin, all my assets are broken. This is due to the fact that my backend is trying to load from

```
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US
```

instead of

```
adminhtml/Magento/backend/fr_FR
```

My question is : How can I make sure the backend load with the correct settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually look like deploying again the static only for the backend area made the trick.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml

Deploy using quick strategy
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2994/2994           
============================ 100%   8 secs              
adminhtml/Magento/backend/fr_FR         2994/2994           
============================ 100%   2 secs
```